# Dividir un select en partes

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hola amigos quiero hacer un query , un select común y corriente , supongamos que tengo 25 registros en una tabla. Y me gustaría que la respuesta de mi query fuese el total de registros entre un número, digamos 5. En ese caso yo quisiera un query algo como:

```
var x = select * from users;
var truequery = x / 5
return truequery
```

en una horrible idea pseudocódigo esto es lo que busco en SQL

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: estoy usando en caso workbench obvio no usa return

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es una query, sería esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/5 FROM users;
```

La función COUNT cuenta todos los registros de la tabla y solo lo divides por el número que quieras. Si lo que quieres es una función, en MySQL sería:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    FUNCTION `dividir`(num INTEGER)
    RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE resultado DECIMAL(10,2);
        SET resultado = (SELECT COUNT(*) / num FROM users);
        RETURN resultado;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Respuesta súper cool, sólo que considero, de forma personal, te faltó indicar cómo mandar a llamar esa función. Además, por si las dudas, yo agregaré en este comentario que a veces puede ser necesario ejecutar un `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` para solventar lo de la cuestión no determinista.